# A released Blazor WebAssembly application redirects API calls to pages instead of the API controller

Tags: azure, blazor, publish, webassembly

I have a Blazor Wasm application with a Client and a Server project. The Client gets is data from the Server by using an api-call. However, when I publish the application to Azure it doesnt work.

Running in Visual Studio:
https://localhost:{number}/api/Project/GetAll returns the expected json.

Published in Azure:
https://{website}.azurewebsites.net/api/Project/GetAll returns the content of the index.html

I think it has something to do with routing but I cannot figure it out.

Note: when I run the project in Release-modus (which accesses the database in Azure) it works as expected.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm not sure 1. where to change the base href manually and 2. to determine what the value should be. Searched SO but couldn't find an answer either.

Comment: I don't think this is my problem: all examples describe the problem when publishing in a subfolder. All my other resources are loaded without problems. Maybe this is crucial information: when I post with Postman to the expected  api-url, I get the index page returned as well.  I don't get what that's got to do with the base href.